# ConstraintLayout - Fixing uneven dp on different device

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

My current constraint layout gives me even spacing in the layout preview and also on my api 28 + 29 emulators, it displays even spacing. However when I use my real api 19 device to test the spacing, it gives me uneven spacing (check picture below). What's the cause for the uneven spacing and how can I fix it so that it's even for all devices?

[image]

**I ended up using guidelines and margins and that fixed the issue:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragevent_threephotolayout_image1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragevent_threephotolayout_image2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/fragevent_threephotolayout_image1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragevent_threephotolayout_image3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/fragevent_threephotolayout_image1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think its because of layout_constraintWidth_percent & layout_constraintHeight_percent because it will differs on various size device so thats why its get changing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must check some ways for it:

1. Don't use percents for width and height
2. Use margin left and right instead of start and end
3. Use padding instead of margin
4. As you see in your images, margin top or bot between 2 images of right side don't have an issue, so you can do what happen between them on others.

Comment: ended up using guidelines and margins and that fixed the issue

Comment: *Don't use percents for width and height* why not? same goes for number 2

Answer (score 0):

different devices have a different screen size that's why uneven space occurs, with 
    help of SDP master we can rectify this issues, below i gave sdp master link kindly add 
    this to yous "res" folder

[kindly go to the link](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) copy dimen value file inside the res folder and paste to 
    you res folder, and use this dimen values instead of manually given size(like 10 dp 
    12 dp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use with Linear Layout as Below

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragevent_threephotolayout_image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: output like this]

Comment: I want to avoid nested layouts